# Find a string and its location in a file

Tags: python-2.7

I want to do three things:

```
1) Print out the ID for each sequence
2) Find a particular motif in a sequence, print it out if it exists
3) Print out the index location for the motif in the sequence
```

Sequence.fasta file example:

```
>sp|Q12955|ANK3_HUMAN Ankyrin-3 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ANK3 PE=1 SV=3
MAHAASQLKKNRDLEINAEEEPEKKRKHRKRSRDRKKKSDANASYLRAARAGHLEKALDY
IKNGVDINICNQNGLNALHLASKEGHVEVVSELLQREANVDAATKKGNTALHIASLAGQA

>sp|Q16659|MK06_HUMAN Mitogen-activated protein kinase 6 OS=Homo sapiens GN=MAPK6 PE=1 SV=1
MAEKFESLMNIHGFDLGSRYMDLKPLGCGGNGLVFSAVDNDCDKRVAIKKIVLTDPQSVK
HALREIKIIRRLDHDNIVKVFEILGPSGSQLTDDVGSLTELNSVYIVQEYMETDLANVLE
QGPLLEEHARLFMYQLLRGLKYIHSANVLHRDLKPANLFINTEDLVLKIGDFGLARIMDP

>sp|Q7Z7A1|CNTRL_HUMAN Centriolin OS=Homo sapiens GN=CNTRL PE=1 SV=2
MKKGSQQKIFKHLQQPSSSHSPIPSSMSNMRSRSLSPLIGSETLPFHSGGQWCEQVEIAD
ENNMLLDYQDHKGADSHAGVRYITEALIKKLTKQDNLALIKSLNLSLSKDGGKKFKYIEN
LEKCVKLEVLNLSYNLIGKIEKLDKLLKLRELNLSYNKISKIEGIENMCNLQKLNLAGNE
```

In this file, I want to find the following motifs (there can be multiple same motifs in the seq.) as an example:

```
MAH..S
KK..D
FES.MN
K..QQ
```

So the output should be:

```
ID = Q12955
Motif = MAH..S
Location =[0] to [4]
Motif = KK..D
Location = [8] to [12]

ID = Q16659
Motif = FES.MN
Location = [4] to [9]

ID = Q7Z7A1
Motif = K..QQ
Location = [1] to [6]
Location = [10] to [14]
```

Code so far:

To find the ID:

```
f=open('pr_seq.fasta','r')

for idLine in f:
    if '>' in idLine:
        lineSplit = idLine.split('|')
        ID = lineSplit[1]
        print ID
```

To find the motifs in the sequence:

```
f=open('pr_seq.fasta','r') 
pr=[]

for motLine in f:
    if motLine[0]=='>':
        pr=motLine.split("\n")[1]

    else:
        try:
            pr+=motLine.strip()
        except:
            pr+=motLine.strip()

    print ("PROTEIN SEQUENCE")      
    print
    print (pr)
    print
```

To find the index locations for the motifs:

```
motif= ['N.E.K..N', 'N.Y....E', 'S...D.PL', 'S..SS','S.S..S', 'F.FP'] 
indices=len(pr)
index=0

for a in motif:
    if re.findall(a,pr):
        print a
        mi = pr.index(a)
```

Comment: I think it would be beneficial, if you simplified your example. Are line breaks treated as blank spaces? Otherwise you can just use grep. Otherwise I would do an implementation yourself of the Knuth-Morris-Prath algorithm.

Comment: In sequence.fasta file there is no blank spaces or line breaks.

Comment: So why did you add line breaks to your example?

Comment: so that if some read can figure out how the sequences are in the file. each sequence starts with ">" sign and the next line is actual sequences.  this is what a fasta file looks like open link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format

Answer (score 0):

Since you explained there are no line breaks, then just do grep:

```
grep MAH..S Sequence.fasta | grep -bo MAH..S
0:MAHAAS

grep KK..D Sequence.fasta | grep -bo KK..D
8:KKNRD
35:KKKSD

grep FES.MN Sequence.fasta | grep -bo FES.MN
4:FESLMN

grep K..QQ Sequence.fasta | grep -bo K..QQ
2:KGSQQ
10:KHLQQ
```

If searching for the pattern twice is allowed, then get the additional information like this:

```
grep -B1 K..QQ Sequence.fasta | awk -F"|" 'NR==1{print $2}'
Q7Z7A1
```

Getting the range is trivial by adding the length of the pattern to the position.

Actually use the module re instead of using grep. I hadn't noticed your question was tagged with Python. Otherwise do a subprocess.call() of grep. In Python it would be:

```
import re
with open('Sequence.fasta') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    m = re.match('MAH..S', line)
    if not m:
        continue
    print(m.start(), m.group())
```

Getting the correct formatting is trivial, which I leave to you. This will *not* match across line breaks, but you say there are no line breaks.

Comment: yeah its python i have used re in motif searching i cannot get the location using index.

Comment: I added the Python solution.